# How to include change/reset password using this type of format of login?

Tags: javascript, html

how do i include a reset button so that i could change or reset the old password and save the new password. Would appreciate if there is a reply. Thank you.

the code
is as following :

HTML

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Log</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div class="pageWidth">
    </div>
</div>
<div>

    <table align = center>
                <tr height = 100 /tr>
                <tr height = 200
                    <td width = 400 align = center id = "box" /td>  
                        <table>
                                <form name="login">
                                <tr id = "spacing" ></tr>
                                <tr align = center <td  colspan =2 /td></tr>
                                    <tr><td width=5>Username:</td><td width=300><input type="text" name="username" autofocus></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td width=5>Password:</td><td width=300><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td colspan = 2 align=right><input id="login" type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                                </form>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

---

```
function check(form)
{
 if(form.username.value == "name" && form.password.value == "pass")
  {
    window.open('');
  }

 else if(form.username.value == "name1" && form.password.value == "pass1")
  {
    window.open('');
  }

 else if(form.username.value == "name2" && form.password.value == "pass2")
 {
   window.open('');
  }

 else
 {
   window.open('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you really doing client-side authentication?

Comment: because apparently, i cannot use php so i can only use html and javascript.

Comment: This type of authentication provides zero security and is sending the correct passwords to everyone who visits your page. Anyone can view the source and see all the correct usernames and passwords

Comment: Is there a better way to use instead of php ?

Comment: Why can't you use your server-side language exactly?

Comment: When i put it in the machine that i suppose to interface, it cannot read php file. To use php file, i need xampp those is it ?